# Sync php and javascript to send data in SQL db

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a loop in javascript file to get variable, i send it in php to insert in SQL.
The problem is that javascript doesn't wait that all informations are insert in SQL db.
Is it possible to sync Javascript and php ?

Part of Js file :

```
while(i<myRoute.steps.length){

var path = myRoute.steps[i].path;

var trajet = path + ''; 

        var data = {
        var2: trajet    
  };  

  $.post("proc.php", data);

  i++;

}
```

proc.php :

```
<?php 

$var2 = $_POST['var2'];

$db = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', '***', '****')  or die('Erreur de connexion '.mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('tc',$db)  or die('Erreur de selection '.mysql_error()); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO ligne(Route) VALUES ('$var2')";

 mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error()); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *third* argument of `$.post`, which is a callback function once a response from the server is received.

```
var i = 0;
var sendData = function(){
   var path = myRoute.steps[i].path;

   var trajet = path + ''; 
   var data = {
        var2: trajet    
   };  

   $.post("proc.php", data, function(){
      if(i < myRoute.steps.length){
         i++;
         sendData();
      }
   });
}
sendData();
```